# Create a Polygon around lines using GPS locations in PHP

Tags: php, geolocation, geospatial

Using PHP, we have an array of GPS coordinates that create a specific route.
I need to allow the user to give an input width. Using this input we need to create a polygon around the line.

In the image found under the link below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DmVdKAh6advlcQYiDZQPsKYisjxmPu5I/view?usp=sharing

We are given the latitude and longitude of the points A,B,C. I need a way to get the coordinates of the points D,E,F,G,H. Note that these are GPS locations and not 2d formulas

Comment: at least give us the code you write, so we can help you

Comment: I did not start writing the code yet, I was hoping someone could suggest a library before i start implementing the equations